# Asynchronous parsing in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I just want to implement a parser to parse my xml. I need clarification from you guys before I start it. Can you guys please suggest a best method or mechanism to parse my xml and rendering it asynchronously.

Comment: How do you parse your XML? Not all appraoches perform the same and you may get more improvement using a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in separate thread. You can
1. open thread yourself
2. use threadpool
3. use Timer.schdule()

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel - [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) does a fantastic job with XML.

As for doing so asynchronously, I would have the parsing thread parse and build whatever data you need, then make it publicly accessible by assigning it to a `volatile` variable once it's done.  You could also use the [callback pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736378/what-is-a-callback-in-java).  Parsing your XML is a separate problem from doing so asynchronously; any asynchronous processing pattern will work just fine.