# What is a callback in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

I have read the wikipedia definition of a callback but I still didn't get it. Can anyone explain me what a callback is, especially the following line

> In computer programming, a callback is a reference to executable code, or a piece of executable code, that is passed as an argument to other code. This allows a lower-level software layer to call a subroutine (or function) defined in a higher-level layer.

Comment: @Pangea Actually, the definition found in that post is the one from wikipedia, and the OP here is asking for a clarification on wikipedia's definition. So, maybe it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Callback in general is a function provided as an argument. Callbacks in Java are Inversion of Control (joke).

Comment: Languages tend to have disparate mechanisms for callbacks.  This can't be a duplicate of a language-agnostic question.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Maybe an example would help.

Your app wants to download a file from some remote computer and then write to to a local disk.  The remote computer is the other side of a dial-up modem and a satellite link. The latency and transfer time will be huge and you have other things to do.  So, you have a function/method that will write a buffer to disk.  You pass a pointer to this method to your network API, together with the remote URI and other stuff.  This network call returns 'immediately' and you can do your other stuff.  30 seconds later, the first buffer from the remote computer arrives at the network layer.  The network layer then calls the function that you passed during the setup and so the buffer gets written to disk - the network layer has 'called back'.  Note that, in this example, the callback would happen on a network layer thread than the originating thread, but that does not matter - the buffer still gets written to the disk.

Comment: But it will work same as if the network function calls the writeToDisk function normally, what's the benefit of a callback?

Comment: @RafaelDiaz . The point here is that the network function cannot (or should not) inherently know/care what you want to do with that data when you get it. So instead of specifying what should be done with the data at compile time, you specify at run time what needs to happen to the data whenever it becomes available. Without callbacks, if you want the "caller" to determine what should be done with the data, your only choice would be to sit and wait for the data and then do it yourself in the caller function.

Answer (score 153):

> Callbacks are most easily described in terms of the telephone system. A function call is analogous to calling someone on a telephone, asking her a question, getting an answer, and hanging up; adding a callback changes the analogy so that after asking her a question, you also give her your name and number so she can call you back with the answer.
>
> Paul Jakubik, *Callback Implementations in C++.*

Answer (score 28):

A callback is some code that you pass to a given method, so that it can be called at a later time.

In Java one obvious example is [`java.util.Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You do not usually use a `Comparator` directly; rather, you pass it to some code that calls the `Comparator` at a later time:

Example:

```
class CodedString implements Comparable<CodedString> {
    private int code;
    private String text;

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals() {
        // member-wise equality
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // member-wise equality 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean compareTo(CodedString cs) {
        // Compare using "code" first, then
        // "text" if both codes are equal.
    }
}

...

public void sortCodedStringsByText(List<CodedString> codedStrings) {
    Comparator<CodedString> comparatorByText = new Comparator<CodedString>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(CodedString cs1, CodedString cs2) {
            // Compare cs1 and cs2 using just the "text" field
        }
    }

    // Here we pass the comparatorByText callback to Collections.sort(...)
    // Collections.sort(...) will then call this callback whenever it
    // needs to compare two items from the list being sorted.
    // As a result, we will get the list sorted by just the "text" field.
    // If we do not pass a callback, Collections.sort will use the default
    // comparison for the class (first by "code", then by "text").
    Collections.sort(codedStrings, comparatorByText);
}
```

Comment: nice answer, good example.

Answer (score 15):

Strictly speaking, the concept of a `callback function` does not exist in Java, because in Java there are no functions, only methods, and you cannot pass a method around, you can only pass objects and interfaces.  So, whoever has a reference to that object or interface may invoke ***any*** of its methods, not just one method that you might wish them to.

However, this is all fine and well, and we often speak of callback objects and callback interfaces, and when there is only one method in that object or interface, we may even speak of a *callback method* or even a *callback function*; we humans tend to thrive in inaccurate communication.

(Actually, perhaps the best approach is to just speak of "a callback" without adding any qualifications: this way, you cannot possibly go wrong. 
 See next sentence.)

One of the most famous examples of using **a callback** in Java is when you call an `ArrayList` object to sort itself, and you supply a comparator which knows how to compare the objects contained within the list.

Your code is the high-level layer, which calls the lower-level layer (the standard java runtime list object) supplying it with an interface to an object which is in your (high level) layer. The list will then be "calling back" your object to do the part of the job that it does not know how to do, namely to compare elements of the list. So, in this scenario the comparator can be thought of as a callback object.

Comment: Unless you count lambda's in Java 8 ... then we have function references!

Comment: Function references in java 8 only look like function references from the caller's point of view.  From the receiving (and calling back) party, they look like (they actually are) regular interfaces.

Answer (score 14):

A callback is commonly used in asynchronous programming, so you could create a method which handles the response from a web service. When you call the web service, you could pass the method to it so that when the web service responds, it call's the method you told it ... it "calls back".

In Java this can commonly be done through implementing an interface and passing an object (or an anonymous inner class) that implements it. You find this often with transactions and threading - such as the Futures API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: Can you please add a simple example Java code with your answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, callback methods are mainly used to address the "[Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)", which is closely related to "Asynchronous Programming".

Although callbacks are also used to simulate passing methods as a parameter, like what is done in functional programming languages.