# Java: Make parameter to a method another method

Tags: java, methods

I want to make a method that does a specific task, but then calls another method with the results of that task.  Well easy enough, but the trick is that I want the method (the second one thats getting called by the first one) to be a parameter of the first method.

I probably explained that terribly, so here is what I think it might look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] data = {
        {2,6},
        {-32,5}
    }

    loop(data,{System.out.println(row * col)});
}

public static void loop(double[][] data,somemethod(row,col)) {
    for (int row = 0;row < data.length;row++)
        for (int col = 0;col < data[0].length;col++)
            somemethod(row,col);
}
```

So the loop method does a task, and then runs the code that was passed as a parameter.  Can this be done in java?  I feel like I have seen it somewhere.

Comment: Yes In [Java8 Lambda Expression](http://java.dzone.com/articles/functional-programming-java-8)

Comment: Is there no way whatsoever to do this for java 7?  Java 7 is ideal for me

Comment: You should consider [Google's Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained)

Comment: There is no [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) in java. In java 7 you can do something "similar" with `interface` (or `abstract class`) .

Comment: @Duffydake , Please read [What are callback in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736378/what-is-a-callback-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pre-Java-8 way to do this was by creating an interface with the method you want called:

```
interface MyCallback {
    void someMethod(int row, int col);
}
```

You create an object with the implementation you want:

```
class MyCallbackImpl implements MyCallback {

    public void somemethod(int row, int col) {
        System.out.println(row * col);
    }
}
```

and have the method take a parameter implementing that interface:

```
public static void loop(double[][] data, MyCallback mycallback) {
    for (int row = 0;row < data.length;row++)
        for (int col = 0;col < data[0].length;col++)
            mycallback.somemethod(row,col);
}
```

If you'd rather not create a separate named class for this you have the alternative of creating an object using an anonymous inner class, calling your loop method like:

```
loop(data, new MyCallback() {
    public void somemethod(int row, int col) {
        System.out.println(row * col);
    }});
```

Comment: Maybe you can include a lambda example as well?

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 the Lambda expressions make that possible. It was not possible before. This is what I know.

Comment: Better to Post your answer with a Working  Example

Comment: Yes, an example would be much appreciated!

Comment: It was technically possible via custom interface

Comment: Ok will add one soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to do this trick!

First, you find the method like this:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
try {
  method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
  // ...
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  // ...
}
```

In your case, you will send methodName and the parameters of methodName as parameters of loop class. After finding the method, you execute it as:

```
try {
  method.invoke(param1, param1,...);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
```

Hope it helps...